# How to use LSTM with sequence data of varying length with keras without embedding?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have an input data where each example is some varying number of vectors of length k. In total I have n examples. So the dimensions of the input is n * ? * k. The question mark symbolizes varying length.

I want to input it to an LSTM layer in Keras, if possible, **without using embedding** (it isn't your ordinary words dataset).

Could someone write a short example of how to do this?

The data is currently a double nested python array, e.g.

```
example1 = [[1,0,1], [1,1,1]]
example2 = [[1,1,1]]
my_data = []
my_data.append(example1)
my_data.append(example2)
```

Comment: I think that if you set None for the number of time steps than the LSTM will be able to take in an input of any length.
so basically the input shape should be (batch_size, None, output_size)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [pad_sequences](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/).  This should get all of your inputs to the same length.

Comment: Yup, but I can't mask_zeros without an embedding layer, which means my model might learn wrong stuff because of all those zeros

Comment: Since NN is just a dot product if your input is all zeros, the output of that layer will be all zeros.  I used this in one of my applications and I had the same feeling you did at the begining.  However, the network gave a zero output during training as well as testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding ([pad_sequences](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/)) and a `Masking` layer.

You can also train batches of different lenghts in a manual training loop:

```
for e in range(epochs):
    for batch_x, batch_y in list_of_batches: #providade you separated the batches by length
        model.train_on_batch(batch_x, batch_y)
```

The keypoint in all of this is that your `input_shape=(None, k)`